# Segmentation fault when calling method on shared_ptr<mock> returned by ON_CALL

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, smart-pointers, googlemock

Im working on a engine class for a game project along with unit tests in google framework.

I've put up a Engine class which takes a CoreBuilder in constructor to initialize Window, Clock, and StateMachine with shared_ptrs (As i want to write UT i want to have these ptrs injectable so i can mock them).

Engine.hpp

```
class Engine : public IEngine
{
public:
    Engine(const ICoreBuilder&);
    virtual ~Engine(){}

    virtual bool isWindowOpen();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<IWindow> window;
    std::shared_ptr<IClock> clock;
    std::shared_ptr<IStateMachine> stateMachine;
    sf::Event sfmlEvent;
};
```

Engine.cpp:

```
Engine::Engine(const ICoreBuilder& builder)
: 
window(builder.createWindow()),
clock(builder.createClock()),
stateMachine(builder.createStateMachine())
{}
```

All these create funcs returns make_shared for each of given objs;

CoreBuilder.hpp

```
class CoreBuilder : public ICoreBuilder
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IWindow> createWindow() const override 
    {return std::make_shared<Window>();}
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IClock> createClock() const override
    {return std::make_shared<Clock>();}
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IStateMachine> createStateMachine() const override
    {return std::make_shared<StateMachine>();}
};
```

I setup a fixture for Engine tests with its sut, Window, Clock and StateMachine as mocks like below:

EngineTests.cpp

```
struct EngineTest : public testing::Test
{
    EngineTest()
    {
        window = std::make_shared<NiceMock<WindowMock>>();
        clock = std::make_shared<NiceMock<ClockMock>>();
        stateMachine = std::make_shared<NiceMock<StateMachineMock>>();
        ON_CALL(coreBuilder, createWindow()).WillByDefault(Return(window));
        ON_CALL(coreBuilder, createClock()).WillByDefault(Return(clock));
        ON_CALL(coreBuilder, createStateMachine()).WillByDefault(Return(stateMachine));
    }

    std::shared_ptr<NiceMock<WindowMock>> window;
    std::shared_ptr<NiceMock<ClockMock>> clock;
    std::shared_ptr<NiceMock<StateMachineMock>> stateMachine;
    NiceMock<CoreBuilderMock> coreBuilder;
    std::unique_ptr<IEngine> sut = std::make_unique<Engine>(coreBuilder);
};
```

The issue is, when i want to test simple function like below:

Engine.cpp

```
bool Engine::isWindowOpen()
{ 
    return window->isActive();
}
```

I get a segfault when sut(Engine) calls for method isWindowOpen

EngineTests.cpp

```
TEST_F(EngineTest, windowIsNotOpenWhenEngineWontRunIt)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*window, isActive()).WillOnce(Return(false));
    ASSERT_FALSE(sut->isWindowOpen()); <-----SEGFAULT
}
```

```
[----------] 5 tests from EngineTest
[ RUN      ] EngineTest.windowIsNotOpenWhenEngineWontRunIt
./runCoreTests.sh: line 10: 17667 Segmentation fault      $exePath
```

I have tried previously doing so on unique_ptrs and setting expectations to return them with ByMove(std::move(mock)), but had same effect and i thought its because move semantics took away that mock from Engine, but here I am with shared_ptr and still with segfault. I have tried to search for similar problem on google like: [Segmentation fault when calling expectation on a pointer return function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275003/segmentation-fault-when-calling-expectation-on-a-pointer-return-function) but failed miserably.

Perhaps there is some point i don't understand or maybe a better way to setup smart_ptr on mocks.

EDIT:

i tried to debug it and while running testcase, during the

```
sut->isWindowOpen()
```

call, window shared_ptr inside sut contains nothing, when it should contain a Window mock object setup in

```
ON_CALL(coreBuilder, createWindow()).WillByDefault(Return(window));
```

and when

```
window->isActive()
```

is called, return false as was setup in

```
EXPECT_CALL(*window, isActive()).WillOnce(Return(false));
```

> Thread 1 "CoreTests" hit Breakpoint 4,
> Core::EngineTest_windowIsNotOpenWhenEngineWontRunIt_Test::TestBody
> (this=0x555555e73160) at
> /home/patelnia/projects/RPGTDD/Tests/Modules/CoreTests/GameTests.cpp:341
> 341         EXPECT_CALL(*window, isActive()).WillOnce(Return(false));
> 1: window = std::shared_ptrtesting::NiceMock<Core::WindowMock> (use
> count 3, weak count 0) = {get() = 0x5555558c18b0} 2: sut =
> std::unique_ptrCore::IEngine = {get() = 0x5555558fd7d0} (gdb) n 342
> ASSERT_FALSE(sut->isWindowOpen()); 1: window =
> std::shared_ptrtesting::NiceMock<Core::WindowMock> (use count 3,
> weak count 0) = {get() = 0x5555558c18b0} 2: sut =
> std::unique_ptrCore::IEngine = {get() = 0x5555558fd7d0} (gdb) n
>
> Thread 1 "CoreTests" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> Core::Engine::isWindowOpen (this=0x5555558fd7d0) at
> /home/patelnia/projects/RPGTDD/Src/Core/Source/Engine.cpp:28 28
> return window->isActive(); 1: window = std::shared_ptrCore::IWindow
> (empty) = {get() = 0x0} 2: sut = <error: There is no member or method
> named sut.>

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Check if `sut` or `sut->window` are null pointers at that time?

Comment: Please don't post the formatted text as the quotation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Complete Verifiable example](https://godbolt.org/z/d8zGdrrcz) based on data provided.

It reprots crashed thread.

```
    #0 0x40a946 in Engine::isWindowOpen() const /app/example.cpp:45
    #1 0x40a946 in EngineTest_windowIsNotOpenWhenEngineWontRunIt_Test::TestBody() /app/example.cpp:100
    #2 0x469a11 in void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (/app/output.s+0x469a11)
    #3 0x46312e in void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (/app/output.s+0x46312e)
    #4 0x441fd7 in testing::Test::Run() (/app/output.s+0x441fd7)
    #5 0x442884 in testing::TestInfo::Run() (/app/output.s+0x442884)
    #6 0x442f12 in testing::TestSuite::Run() (/app/output.s+0x442f12)
    #7 0x44e093 in testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (/app/output.s+0x44e093)
    #8 0x46abd6 in bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (/app/output.s+0x46abd6)
    #9 0x46418a in bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (/app/output.s+0x46418a)
    #10 0x44cb71 in testing::UnitTest::Run() (/app/output.s+0x44cb71)
    #11 0x408ac3 in RUN_ALL_TESTS() (/app/output.s+0x408ac3)
    #12 0x408a5c in main (/app/output.s+0x408a5c)
    #13 0x7f3161ef6082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
    #14 0x40896d in _start (/app/output.s+0x40896d)
```

After that I immediately see that problem is order of initialization.

First fields are initialized so constructor of `Engine` is called and after that mock is configured! So constructor gets nulptr-s.
Please learn to use debugger ASAP since with this tool you would find this problem in 10 seconds (literally).

[Here is fixed version](https://godbolt.org/z/3To4cr9G8).